# Can I transfer my openID to another openID?

Tags: discussion, accounts

I made a mistake 4 years ago: I registered my university's gmail account as my stackexchange openID. But as I'm close to finishing my education I will lose access to this account, is there a way to keep my score or is it my own fault for not thinking ahead?

Comment: If you add another OAuth to your account (In your Profile, go to Settings then My Logins) then you can use that.

Comment: Here's the help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: It's exactly the answer I needed, so if you like you can post it as an answer and I will accept it